# $T(A)=BA$ implies geometric multiplicity of every eigenvalue of $T$ is $\ge n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $T: \mathbb C ^{n  \times n} \to \mathbb C ^{n  \times n}$ defined by $T(A)=BA$.
>
> $A,B \in \mathbb C ^{n  \times n}$.
>
> (I already proved that every eigenvalue of $T$ is eigenvalue of $B$, and vice versa.)
>
> Prove:
>
> - Geometric multiplicity of every eigenvalue of $T$ is $\ge n$.

Comment: How did you prove that they have the same eigenvalues?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $x$ be an eigenvector of $B$. Let $A$ be a matrix with zeros in every column except for the $j$th column, and take the $j$th column to be the vector $x$.

Comment: We can make $n$ linearly independent eigen-matrices of $T$ using any one eigenvector of $B$.